# Python Pandas Series Keep Only Null Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series that has `None` values in some columns. I would like to keep only the keys with `None` values. There must be a native pandas function that does this! For DataFrames, it's easy to create a mask and filter, but not sure how to do it for a Series.

Example Input:

```
import pandas as pd

my_series = pd.Series({
    "foo": "some string",
    "bar": "some string",
    "bam": None,
})
```

Expected Output

```
new_series =my_series.DO_SOMETHING()
new_series = pd.Series({
    "bam": None,
})
```

What would this DO_SOMETHING be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `isna` and `isnull`

```
my_series[my_series.isnull()] # isna
Out[824]: 
bam    None
dtype: object
```